# Creating if functions with checkboxes in R-shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently doins a personal project to get used to using R-shiny. I am using the `penguins` dataset in R. This project is creating several different boxplots. I have been able to create the main code for the boxplots to show and now I am trying to use the checkbox input to allow the user to select if it wants the boxplots to be divided by the Islands ivestigated or rather just see the data as it.

My code is the following.

```
library("palmerpenguins")
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")
penguins.data<- penguins
sum(is.na(penguins))
#As their are a few penguins with missing values (19 out of 2752) we decide to carry out the data visualization with
#Only the complete cases of the data

penguins.data<-na.omit(penguins.data)

#Making sure the categorical variables are factors
str(penguins.data)
penguins.data$species<-as.factor(penguins.data$species)
penguins.data$sex<-as.factor(penguins.data$sex)
penguins.data$year<-as.factor(penguins.data$year)
penguins.data$island<-as.factor(penguins.data$island)

#Defining the UI for the App.
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Adding a suitable title
  titlePanel("Penguin exploration"),
  #Getting the layout
  sidebarLayout(
    #Setting the panel for the used to select the inputs they want
    sidebarPanel(
      #Selecting the variable for the X-axis
      selectInput("horiz", "Select x-axis variable:",
                  c("Sex" = "sex",
                    "Species" = "species",
                    "Year" = "year"),
                 selected = "sex" ),
      
      
       #Selecting the variable in the Y-axis
      selectInput("vert", "Select y-axis variable:",
                  c("Bill Length" = "bill_length_mm",
                    "Bill Depth" = "bill_depth_mm",
                    "Flipper length" = "flipper_length_mm",
                    "Body mass" = "body_mass_g"),
                  selected = "flipper_length_mm" ),
      
     #We create the checkbox input for the user to select if they want to see the data in 
      checkboxInput("Divide", "check to look at how data is divided by Island Level", value = F)),
  
    
    mainPanel(
      #Setting a title for the output
      h3("plot"),
      
      #We decide how to name the plot to use it in the output
      plotOutput("PengPlot")
    ),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  horizontal<-reactive(input$horiz)
  vertical<-reactive(input$vert)
  
  
   output$PengPlot <- renderPlot({
     if(output$Divide){
       
     ggplot(data = penguins.data, aes_string(horizontal(), vertical()))+
     geom_boxplot(aes(fill= island))+
       facet_wrap(~horizontal())
       
     }else{
       
       ggplot(data = penguins.data, aes_string(horizontal(), vertical()))+
         geom_boxplot()
     }
   })
  }
  


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am currently getting the error `Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed.` I am lost on what specifically to do. I am considering if maybe creating both boxplots as reactive objects and then use the if functions but I have seen in other posts that doing that may overcomplicate the code.

Any advice or help will be great. Thank in advance

Comment: Your server-definition contains the following code ` if(output$Divide)`, while you probably mean  `if(input$Divide)`.

Comment: Yes thank you that was the issue. I though everything that I had to relate in the if function to the output in the server instead than to the input in the ui.